# Determine a set is Linearly independant

Tags: abstract-algebra

given a set like $\{1,\sin^2x, \cos2x, \cos^2x\}$ in a field how do i prove linear Independence?, or with polynomials with quadratics and constants i.e. $\{x^2,x,1\}$

Comment: If I read it correct what you have inside the brackets, I see $sin^2x$ and $cos^2x$. Now isn't there some identity for those?

Comment: Use the definition of linear independence. You have to take into account which are the vectors and which are the scala. $\{x^2, x, 1\}$ are linearly independent if your scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$, but linearly dependent over the field of rational functions $\mathbb{R}(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

for the first set we have:
$$
\sin^2x +\cos^2x=1 \qquad and \qquad \cos^2x-\sin^2x=\cos 2x
$$

for the second: when $ax^2+bx+c\cdot 1=0$ **for any value** of $x$?